# Sample count mismatching in JMeter Aggregate Report

Tags: jmeter

In the aggregate report we are seeing discrepancy in the sample count almost 50% but sample count in beginning (launching home page) and end ( logout) are almost same, Its kind of drop in samples for that call and it is consistently happening even we executes it local. there is no error% as well.
Meanwhile there is no success checkbox checked in the aggregate report listener as well. There is no suspicious behavior in the server side as well. Can anyone help on this?

I have executed a Jmeter script for 30 mins with 50 users with rampup period of 15 minutes.
Scenario includes launching home page, logging in to logout.